# Elementor Widget not able to locate my Class, returning Fatal Error

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, fatal-error, elementor

I'm new to developing Elementor Widgets, so in my theme folder I created a custom-elementor.php file to make a call to a PHP file in a widgets folder I created. Should work, but for some reason, it can't locate the class I created in my file.

Basically it calls a fatal error that starts like this:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'datacoral\Widgets\Post_Grid' not found in /home/customer/www/staging2.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/my-theme/custom-elementor.php:27

Here's the code in my custom-elementor.php file:

```
namespace postgrid;
class Widget_Loader{
  private static $_instance = null;
  public static function instance()
  {
    if (is_null(self::$_instance)) {
      self::$_instance = new self();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
  }
  private function include_widgets_files(){
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/widgets/post_grid.php');
  }
  public function register_widgets(){
  $this->include_widgets_files();
    \Elementor\Plugin::instance()->widgets_manager->register_widget_type(new Widgets\Post_Grid()); // Call to locate class aka line 27
  }
  public function __construct(){
    add_action('elementor/widgets/widgets_registered', [$this, 'register_widgets'], 99);
  }
}
Widget_Loader::instance();
```

And then in that post_grid file, which is too long to post here, all that really matters is this:

```
class Post_Grid extends Widget_Base
```

Like I said, new to all this but this looks right, so why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is namespace you used inside Post_Grid?
if your namespace is datacoral\Widgets you should set it same as Widget_Loader (postgrid\Widgets) OR import it (use datacoral\Widgets;) in top of code to access the Post_Grid class

Comment: So this is where I'm confused. Originally the namespace in my post_grid.php file was datacoral\grid and obviously, that's wrong. However, I tried a bunch of different namespaces to find one that works for me but nothing does. 

The namespace now in my post_grid file is namespace datacoral\Widgets\Post_Grid but that's probably wrong too.

Comment: I just figured it out and it seemed having the namespace capitalized (go figure) and just having Datacoral\Widgets on the postgrid file worked. Thanks for clearing it ujp.